# Selenium CSS selector for nth occurrence of td span:nth-child(2)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

The css selector `td span:nth-child(2)` means the 2nd child node `span` of `td`. I wanna choose the nth `td span:nth-child(2)`, something like:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("td span:nth-child(2):eq(4)")
```

I know I can use

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td span:nth-child(2)")[4]
```

or xpath instead:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//td/span[2])[4]')
```

I just wanna know if I can do the same thing with css selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with a CSS selector. `:eq()` is from jQuery and not part of any standard.

`td:nth-child(4) span:nth-child(2)` means something entirely different, and will only work in very specific situations, such as when there is exactly one table row with four `td` elements all of which contain at least two `span` children:

```
<body>
  ...
  <table>
    <!-- The first, or only, row in the entire document
         with this many cells containing this many spans -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      <td>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      <td>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      <td>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
  </table>
  ...
</body>
```

It won't match the element you're looking for in this example, because each `tr` has only two `td` children, so `td:nth-child(4)` will never match:

```
<body>
  ...
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      <td>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      <td>
        <span></span>
        <span></span> <!-- (//td/span[2])[4] -->
  </table>
  ...
</body>
```

If you know `td:nth-child(4) span:nth-child(2)` is guaranteed to work in your situation though, feel free to use it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm working with the later case. I'll take  `xpath` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you can use `nth-child()` on the `td` as well:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td:nth-child(4) span:nth-child(2)")
```