# I am unable to iterate(locate) this input filed from selenium python, every time id changed, and full Xpath is also not working

Tags: python, selenium, automation

Hy all, I am unable to iterate this input filed from selenium python, every time id changed, and full Xpath is also not working.
URL: https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/3091837

i tried already: -

```
driver.find_element_by_name("blog_URL").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="render_api158171433--blog_URL"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div/section/div/div[1]/article/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[1]/input").click()
driver.find_element_by_id('render_api535892960--blog_URL')[2].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<input>` has an slippery id but its name seems to be unique `name="blog_URL"`, so you could use **find_element_by_name**

Anyway when an id or class changes every time, findById or xpath with exact values does not help.

You can try other approaches such as: looking for neighbors, parents, children,sibling, etc., which can be located and then navigate until to find your slippery `<input>`. This will be a little expensive!!

Samples according to your html:

## form has an unique id

- locate form by id = harassment

```
parentElement = driver.find_element_by_id("myFormId")
```

- get all child elements

```
childElementsOfForm = parentElement.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*")
```

- Iterate elements and get the second and perform a new find inside of this element. We can see that our `<input>` in another child of it.

## search all inputs in form

```
parentElement = driver.find_element_by_id("myFormId")
elementList = parentElement.find_elements_by_tag_name("input")
```

Iterate them and search an input whose id starts with **render_api**

## Locating elements using advanced CSS selectors

- https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781849515740/1/ch01lvl1sec17/locating-elements-using-advanced-css-selectors
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31779797/3957754

Comment: unable to locate from this method.